# Appium iOS dismiss alert fails for the first time only with connection reset error

Tags: automation, appium, appium-ios

I am testing an application where I have to dismiss the alert shown for the wrong email format. The case is failing for the first time and if I manually dismiss, the other test cases for all other Invalid cases and pop up dismiss works.

I am using

```
public void dismissAlert() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(appDriver, 1000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
    appDriver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();

}
```

Where appDriver is

```
protected static AppiumDriver appDriver;
```

The code ( cases ) execute to this point correctly and then the error is thrown:

```
   [31morg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{0.0.0.0:4723, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=/0.0.0.0:4723 cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1}
  Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
```

Maven Dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is connection reset error pop up system pop up or app pop up?

Comment: It's the iOS alert and its in app implementation. so app pop up

Comment: Did you solve it?